# Where am I wrong when calculating $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}5k \frac{1}{6^{k-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}5k \frac{1}{6^{k-1}}$

so what I did is $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}5k \frac{1}{6^{k-1}} = 5\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k (\frac{1}{6})^{k-1} =  5\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} ((\frac{1}{6})^{k})' = 5 (\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{6})^{k})' = 5* \frac{\frac{1}{6^2}}{1-\frac{1}{6}} = \frac{1}{6}$

But the answer should be $\frac{11}{5}$.

I guess I should change the $k$ i'm summing for when taking the derivative maybe?

But I'm not sure why.

Can anyone pinpoint my mistake and explain why it is wrong?

Comment: You differentiate with respect to what variable?

Comment: @Gary $x=\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: I think you forgot to actually differentiate the sum of infinite geometric series.

Comment: $(a^x)'=a^x\cdot \log a$

Comment: You cannot differentiate with respect to a constant. Anyhow, $$
\left( {\frac{1}{{1 - x}}} \right)^\prime   = \frac{1}{{(1 - x)^2 }}.
$$

Comment: @player3236 oh that is right...
my bad, thank you :)

Comment: @Gary I'm thinking about it as a power series, you can think of x instead of 1/6

Comment: Still, the other comments are valid: $(\sum(1/6)^k)'$ does not make any sense, and this shorthand indirectly caused your mistake.

Comment: You better write something like $$
\left[ {\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {x^k } } \right)} \right]_{x = 1/6} .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Can you differentiate a constant? Yes, but the result is zero. Sorry, but your method is completely wrong.

You can leave out the constant factor $5$ for the moment and consider
$$
f(t)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty kt^{k-1}
$$
If we integrate from $0$ to $x$, we get, for $|x|<1$,
$$
\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x
$$
so if we differentiate
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-1
$$
With $x=1/6$ and deploying the factor $5$ we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty 5k\frac{1}{6^{k-1}}=\frac{5}{(1-1/6)^2}-5=5\cdot\frac{36}{25}-5=\frac{11}{5}
$$